# Power Query refresh source table only if not recently refreshed

Tags: excel, vba, refresh, powerquery

I have source data in excel workbook that is loaded to Power Query to clean data and result is only connection. (Excel Table => PQ connection ("Main table"))

Then I created two separate tables from this connection ("Main table") that are loaded to worksheets.

PQ connection ("Main table") => Table1

PQ connection ("Main table") => Table2

The thing is that when I refresh these tables (in VBA) like

```
     ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Table1").Refresh
     ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Table2").Refresh
```

every time is refreshed also Main table what takes significant time that is not necessary. I do not need to refresh it every time. Is it possible to solve this?

Comment: The code on https://www.excelcampus.com/library/enable-background-refresh-on-all-power-query-connections/ might help